# How can I express this shape as a parameterized function?

Tags: geometry, analysis, parametric

I want a (hopefully continuous) function that can describe the following shape. Although the image is not exact, I want the expression to include an increase in crest amplitudes.

[image]

For reference, this is an image of a self replicating nano-scale crack in which the delamination and fracture occurs simultaneously to create these amazing shapes. I am trying to backwards engineer an interaction between these two forces to create specific shapes. In order to do that, I need the position function of the crack front. (this crack front position function is what I am asking about)

Answer (score 4):

It *looks like* a "bent" sine wave. So something like

$$\alpha(t) = (st+b\cos(2t), a\sin(t))$$

The $b$ affects the "bendiness", the $a$ affects the amplitude and $s$ affects the "spaciness."

e.g. $s=1, a=8$ and $b=1$ produces

[image]

Link to play around: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/akokhmswfi

**Edit:** Based on Alexis Olson's suggestion, here is a model where amplitude grows slowly:

https://www.desmos.com/calculator/zgv64n0voe

Comment: And to have the amplitude increase dependent on $t$, replace $a$ with whatever function that represents the growth. For example: $(2t+8\cos(2t),(1+\sqrt{t})\sin(t))$

Comment: Hi, I was wondering if there is an analytical expression for b. Is it simply the curvature (1/R). In this case, the plot doesn't look right. Do you know of any way to relate b to the period or amplitude?